# java error while installing scilab in raspberry pi

Tags: java, raspberry-pi2

I have successfully installed IPD toolbox in ubuntu 14.04 desktop not in raspberrypi by same procedure but when I am installing image processing design toolbox(IPD) in scilab 5.5.0 on **lubuntu 14.04 or xubuntu** in **raspberry pi**:-
When I am installing Source version of IPD it gives following error:-

```
Building the manual file [javaHelp] in /home/ubuntu/IPD/help/en_US.
 !--error 999 
buildDoc: Error while building documentation: Java heap space.
at line     696 of function xmltoformat called by :  
at line      17 of function xmltojar called by :  
at line      51 of function tbx_build_help called by :  
olute_file_path("build_help.sce"))
at line      18 of exec file called by :    

at line      13 of function tbx_builder called by :  
at line      49 of function tbx_builder_help_lang called by :  
ute_file_path("builder_help.sce"))
at line      27 of exec file called by :    
at line      13 of function tbx_builder called by :  
at line      26 of function tbx_builder_help called by :  
at line      34 of function main_builder called by :  
main_builder();
at line      61 of exec file called by :    
exec('builder.sce')

                    !--error 999 
buildDoc: Execution Java stack:  at com.sun.java.help.search.IntegerArray.growArray(IntegerArray.java:68)
 at com.sun.java.help.search.IntegerArray.add(IntegerArray.java:62)
 at com.sun.java.help.search.DocumentLists.process(DocumentLists.java:232)
 at com.sun.java.help.search.DocumentLists$MicroIndex.process(DocumentLists.java:152)
 at com.sun.java.help.search.DocumentLists.<init>(DocumentLists.java:200)
 at com.sun.java.help.search.DocumentLists.invert(DocumentLists.java:270)
 at com.sun.java.help.search.DefaultIndexBuilder.close(DefaultIndexBuilder.java:130)
 at com.sun.java.help.search.Indexer.compile(Indexer.java:242)
 at org.scilab.modules.helptools.JarOnlyConverter.convert(Unknown Source)
 at org.scilab.modules.helptools.SciDocMain.process(Unknown Source)
.

                    !--error 999 
If Scilab is started in a chroot, you might want to try to set the two environment variables: SCI_DISABLE_TK=1 SCI_JAVA_ENABLE_HEADLESS=1
```

Please give me suggestions

Thanks